# How compiler is knowing about head in linkedlist

Tags: java, linked-list

How here head is automatically got the address of the node when we did not pointed we just created a node with name head
`we are directly using the head as if head is not equal to null do this but how head is getting any value in it thats my question.

```
public class Main {
    public int size ;
    Main(){
        this.size=0;
    }
    Node head;
    class Node{
        String data;
        Node next;
        Node(String data){
            this.data= data;
            this.next=null;
            size++;
        }
    }
    // add in first
    public void addFirst(String data){
        Node Newnode = new Node(data);
        if (head == null){
            head = Newnode;
            return;
        }
        Newnode.next=head;
        head=Newnode;
    }
}
```

Comment: "*head is automatically got the address of the node*" that is exactly done by the statement(s) `head=Newnode;` ! BTW the whole `if` block  is not needed at all

Comment: The code is assigning to `head` in two places in `addFirst`.  If you are asking how `head` gets a value in the first place, it is an field of the `Main` class, and fields are default initialized to `null`.